# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{9}{4^n}.$

Tags: calculus, summation, power-series

> Evaluate $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n-1}\frac{9}{4^n}.$$

My approach:  using $\frac{a}{1-r}$, we have

$\frac{9}{1-\frac{1}{4}} = 12$

But the correct answer is $\frac{9}{5}$

What am I missing in solving this problem?

Comment: Recall that the power series is represented by $$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=\color{blue}0}^\infty x^n, |x|<1.$$

Comment: $(-1)^{n-1}\frac{9}{4^n}$ can be written as $\frac 94(-\frac 14)^{n-1}$, so the answer is $$\frac{\frac 94}{1-\bigg(\color{red}-\frac 14\bigg)}$$

Answer (score 1):

To relate the given expression $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac9{4^n}$$ to the known power series $$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n, |x|<1,$$ we can write 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1}\frac9{4^n}&=9\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)\left(-\frac14\right)^n\\&=-9\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac14\right)^{n+1}\\&=-9\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac14\right)^{n}\cdot\left(-\frac14\right)\\&=\frac94\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac14\right)^n.
\end{align}

Since $\left|-\dfrac14\right|<1,$  therefore, we can write $$\frac94\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(-\frac14\right)^n=\frac94\left(\frac{1}{1-(-\frac14)}\right)=\frac94\cdot\frac45=\frac95$$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

If the $r$th term is $$T_m=(-1)^{m-1}\dfrac9{4^m},$$

$\dfrac{T_{m+1}}{T_m}=-\dfrac14$

So, your $r\ne\dfrac14$